# Can anyone solve this ListView onItemClickListener Error? Also getting bug in searchView

Tags: java, android, searchview

**ItemModel.java**

```
package com.example.poptunemusicplayer;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ItemModel implements Serializable {
    private String name;

    public ItemModel(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Getting Error due to ***String songName = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(i);*** at listView.setOnItemClickListener;

**Code in MainActivity.java**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String songName = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerActivity.class)
                        .putExtra("songs", mySongs)
                        .putExtra("songname", songName)
                        .putExtra("position", i));
            }
        });
```

Trying to set onClick in listView in my application but this errors occurs

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.poptunemusicplayer, PID: 7781
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.poptunemusicplayer.ItemModel cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at com.example.poptunemusicplayer.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:112)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:350)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1674)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:4085)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$10.run(AbsListView.java:6573)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7025)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

I have also implemented serachView but getting wrong results after I write something on it and also getting some different results at onClick. For eg;

Suppose in my list I have some items like:

- To You
- Young
- Astronomia
- Love me like you do
- Honest
- Closer

If I type on search "you" its giving me the result:

- To You
- Love me like you do

Its not showing me the "Young" and if I click on "Love me like you do" then its shows me the data of "Young".
Neither fetching the correct data nor correct position.

**getFilter() method in CustomAdapter**

```
@Override
        public Filter getFilter(){
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint == null | constraint.length() == 0){
                        filterResults.count = itemsModelsl.size();
                        filterResults.values = itemsModelsl;
                    }
                    else {
                        List<ItemModel> resultModel = new ArrayList<>();
                        String searchStr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                        for (ItemModel itemModel: itemsModelsl){
                            if (itemModel.getName().contains(searchStr)){
                                resultModel.add(itemModel);
                            }
                            filterResults.count = resultModel.size();
                            filterResults.values = resultModel;
                        }
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    itemsModelListFiltered = (List<ItemModel>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
```

**SearchView Code in OptionsMenu() method**

```
case R.id.searchid:

                SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
                SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
                searchView.setQueryHint("Type here to search");

                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                        customAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                        return true;

                    }
                });

                return true;
```

Which step am I missing here ?

Comment: Added a SearchView bug occuring in my application.

Comment: Hi again @Kaliash8640, you should create a separate question regarding the search view bug :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, your `ListView` adapter contains instances of the class `ItemModel` and not just simple `String`s.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.poptunemusicplayer.ItemModel cannot be cast to java.lang.String

To remedy this, change this

```
String songName = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

to

```
ItemModel itemModel = (ItemModel) listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
String songName = itemModel.getName();
```

and it should no longer crash.

A recommendation on my end would be to look into using `RecyclerView` down the road, but that's a topic for another day.

Comment: Thanks for help but I need help at one more point;